# Java Slick making character rotate to selected degree

Tags: java, rotation, lwjgl, slick2d, game-ai

I have run into a issue while coding my game. I am using Slick Libraries and Light Weight Java Games libraries. I am trying to make my player (Plane) go to a certain area on the map. For example if I set the target coords to (50,50) My plane will go to 50 on the X and then go to 50 on they Y. But I am stuck on rotation. I am trying to get my plane to rotate to 90 degrees, like a player would if he was controlling it, So I don't want to just set the rotation I want it to rotate at the normal rate (0.2*delta), until it hits 90 degrees.

The code bellow will only work if the plane is rotated facing left currently.

This is my Current code.

```
if(AIToggle){
 AIStatus = "ON";

 if(TargetX < x){
 if(plane.getRotation() < 0 ){


 if(plane.getRotation()<=-270 ){
 plane.rotate(-0.2f * delta);
      }

   }

  } 
}
```

What it currently does: If the plane is rotated left more then 90 degrees and AI is on then it will slowly rotate it to 0 degrees. Which is what I don't understand.

What I am trying to get it to do: If the plane is rotated left more then 90 degrees, rotate the plane to -90 degrees then stop.

Comment: Thus has been resolved it should have been "plane.getRotation()>=-270"

Comment: You should write that as an answer, then accept it so this no longer shows up as unanswered.

Comment: I can't because my rep is too low.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by changing

`plane.getRotation()<=-270`

to

`plane.getRotation()>=270`

(posted as answer since the original poster was unable to do so)